# react native calendar disable touch event on sundays

Tags: react-native, calendar, expo

hi i'm new to react native i'm trying to disable Sundays and all dates before today date i'm using react-native-calendars i managed to disable all the Sundays but the touch event still works 
any help please ?

```
here's the code to disable sundays
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { isSunday } from "date-fns";
import Day from "react-native-calendars/src/calendar/day/basic";

export class CustomDay extends Component {
  render() {
    const { date, marking } = this.props;
    marking.disabled = isSunday(date.timestamp);
    return <Day {...this.props} />;
  }
}
```

`````
<Calendar
  dayComponent={props => {
    return <CustomDay {...props} />;
  }}
/>
````
`````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try this?

`react-native-calendars` has a default event set. However, the value `true` and `false` are not specified when the value is `disabled`.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { isSunday } from "date-fns";
import Day from "react-native-calendars/src/calendar/day/basic";

export class CustomDay extends Component {
  render() {
    const { date, marking } = this.props;
    marking.disabled = isSunday(date.timestamp);
     marking.disableTouchEvent = marking.disabled === true ? true : false
    return <Day {...this.props} />;
  }
}
```

[reference link](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars)

Definition of `Day`

```js
 <TouchableOpacity
        testID={this.props.testID}
        style={containerStyle}
        onPress={this.onDayPress}
        onLongPress={this.onDayLongPress}
        activeOpacity={marking.activeOpacity}
        disabled={marking.disableTouchEvent}
      >
        <Text allowFontScaling={false} style={textStyle}>{String(this.props.children)}</Text>
        {dot}
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: biiig thanks it works and how can i disable days before today date ?

Comment: @AhmedEssaadi you can use minDate https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/blob/master/src/calendar/index.js#L34

Comment: hi i just found out that touch event on all days doesn't work not only Sundays any help please ? you can check it here [link](https://snack.expo.io/@ahmedsaadi/amused-ice-cream)